# javafx : extends a class scene in javafx

Tags: javafx

I created a javafx home class which inherits from the scene class to customize the home scene of my application, but nothing works

```
public class AcceuilScene extends Scene {

    public AcceuilScene(Parent root) {
        super(root);
    }
}
```

Comment: don't .. a scene is meant to be configured (_not_ extended). What do you want to achieve?

Comment: As stated in a previous comment, subclassing `Scene` is always a bad design choice. That said, it's possible and should work. What does "nothing works" mean? What happens when you try to use this?

Comment: @kleopatra Why is extending from `Scene` a bad thing?

Comment: @James_D Perhaps you or kleopatra can post an Answer to this Question to explain (a) why extending from Scene is to be discouraged, and (b) a workaround. I assume the workaround is to extend from a layout class such as `VBox`, and add an instance of that subclass to a non-subclassed `Scene` object.

Comment: @BasilBourque I’m not sure the actual question (if there is a question here) is answerable. There is nothing in the posted code that “doesn’t work”. It just doesn’t do anything. `new AcceuilScene()` is identical to `new Scene()`. Clearly the OP intends to do something else, but without knowing what it’s impossible to say what the correct approach is.